# How to inject window object in test spec file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, protractor

I have set up an AngularJS application on Electron (former atom-shell) and e2e-testing using Protractor. I would now like to unit-test it.
My attempt at testing it using command `$ protractor conf.js` result with an error:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

This error comes from requiring `angular-mocks`. Looking at `angular-mocks.js`, it takes `window` and `window.angular` as entry parameters. I don't know how I can inject it into my file to solve this error.
The code I'm trying to use:

**test-spec.js**

```
describe('appController', function () {

    require('angular-mocks');

    var $controller;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    it('should return empty string',
            function () {
                var $scope = {};
                var controller = $controller('appController', 
                {$scope:$scope});
                var result = $scope.generateString(12, 'blue');
                expect(result).toEqual("");
            });
});
```

Do you know a way to solve this issue?

Comment: `protractor` is a tool for end-to-end testing, not unit testing. You may need to look into `karma`.